# Ember-cli non ember function

Tags: ember-cli

I already worked with emberjs before it used ember-cli but now I am not sure how I can do that.

I need to create some functions to manage my cookies and some other thing, but I don't know where I should put them in the project so they will be available from anywhere (controller, routes, views...). I looked at the emberjs guide/doc but I can't find anything relevant about that unfortunatelly..

Is there is a specific place I can put my functions ? or I have to copy/paste them everywhere ?
Should I put my scripts inside the vendor folder ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve with your Ember application? If it's just a few scripts & functions (not a full blown single page web app), you might be better off staying away from Ember as it's intended for bigger applications that would warrant taking advantage of Ember.

Comment: I am using ember for a big app, but I needed some non ember function on the side that needed to be accessible from every controlers/routers/views, like some cookie verification and some others functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place it in a util script. To create one, type in *ember generate util foo*

Take note that it uses ES6 syntax with the export default and stuff.

Once you have the util script you can import it in your controller, route, etc.